# : error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to c# and unity and I don't know what this error means, i'm trying to make the floor tilt like in super monkey ball, I know how it all works but I copied and pasted it so to not make mistakes and to save time.

This is the code, please help

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Floor_Control : MonoBehaviour{}
{
    public float speed;
    public float max;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Player Input
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        float tiltX = -Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") +         Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        float tiltZ = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") +     Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().rotation =     Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation,     Quaternion.Euler(max * tiltZ, 0, max * tiltX), step);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's this: `MonoBehaviour{}` ... the whole class is within those curly braces. The ones that follow are bare (they don't belong to a class declaration).

Comment: Remove the `{} ` after MonoBehavior.

Comment: UnityScript is a JavaScript-like language that was deprecated in 2017.  You're using C#, so I've replaced `unityscript`with the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the braces after MonoBehaviour  "{}".  You also don't have a namespace declaration which may also generate that error message:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

namespace TestProgram
{
    public class Floor_Control : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public float speed;
        public float max;

        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            //Player Input
            float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
            float tiltX = -Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") +         Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            float tiltZ = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") +     Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().rotation =     Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation,     Quaternion.Euler(max * tiltZ, 0, max * tiltX), step);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A namespace isn't necessary, but if the namespace and open curly brace lines were removed and the closing curly brace was not, that *would* generate this error or something similar.